# Android app for morsecode using camera flash

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I am trying to develop an app which transmits morse code using camera flash light on phone. My transmitting part works fine. I am turning flash on based on DOT or DASH and off based on GAP, LETTER_GAP and WORD_GAP. all DOT, DASH, GAP, LETTER_GAP and WORD_GAP has different time duration for which they will be ON or OFF.

I have difficult time figuring out how to decode this on receiver side...I am using opencp binary threshold to see if there exist a bright spot in the image and not. Based on camera fps I can  calculate how many frames had flash on or off consecutively which determines dot/dash/gap. here is the example.

Say from transmitter phone i am sending "abc xyz" as string. on receiver phone I am getting these String

.*-#-*.*.*.#-*.*-*. -*.*.*-#-*.*-*-#-*-*.*. where,

"." - DOT
"-" - DASH
"*" - GAP
"#" - LETTER GAP
" " - WORD GAP

this string is exactly represents "abc xyz". The problem is **I can not think of a way for receiver phone where to start looking for new message and when to stop**, as everything is being sent using light signals. there is no sync between transmit and receive. I mean there is no way for receiver to identify start and end signal as i just process raw camera frames provided by opencv. **Is there any way i can impose these?** or alternative solution to make detection/decoding?

Please let me know if I am not clear. Thank You!

Comment: nice idea, my kids love it already ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there can be multiple answers. First you can ask for manual input from the receiver and analyze all frames for the first seconds. Perhaps you can always monitor and set a threshhold on the light pattern strength. You can also make a re-sync sequence where the sender shines the light for exactly one second and starts transmission. This would be the handshake and the rest the message.

Great work and hopefully you make an app out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the approach Shivam Kalra used here:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46174/Computer-Vision-Decoding-a-Morse-Code-Flashing-LED

tldr: allow user to set a coordinate in the picture frame and monitor brightness of the pixel(s) underneath the coordinate.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.